# Ghost-Imaging the BOOTCAMP partition for later restore?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, partition

I have a MacBook and I plan to upgrade to Windows 10 but want to be able to roll-back to the original Windows 7 in case Windows 10 is not good for me.

I have used Symantec Ghost to do a Hot-image (i.e. create image when Windows 7 is running instead of booting from a CD), I also imaged the "System" partitions.

However, I still haven't gone ahead for the upgrade, as I am new in doing the ghost imaging, and I'm not confident that the image I created can restore the MacBook's Windows 7 to the original. Since it is running in Boot Camp I fear the imaging might have to be done different than ordinary Windows 7 installations. Also I'm not sure if the partitioning data (partition table, MBR, GPT, VBR, boot loader, or whatever it is), or any other vital data that I am not aware of, is really successfully preserved in the image I created.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: You might want to look at [Winclone](http://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone), which is designed for OS X to backup and restore the Windows BOOTCAMP Partition from OS X.

Comment: So it seems like the imaging of Bootcamp partitions needs specialized imaging software instead of generic ones? Coz I saw Winclone popping up all the time during my searching of the subject in Google and SO

Answer (score 1):

I would say you're not on the right track doing an update before you test if your backup works on Windows 7 to Windows 7 first.

Without knowing what version of OS X and Boot Camp, people might hesitate to report success or failure, but since Apple doesn't "support" Boot Camp you might check with Symantec to make sure you are able to use their support if you need it.

Are you locked into Boot Camp? It seems you would benefit from having virtual machines you could snapshot and test and co-exist so you don't need to depend on a restore to bare metal scenario.

Comment: I'm not sure if the version of OS X matters, as I believe the partition layout between recent os x versions should not be too different

Comment: It is El capitan anyway